# How would I separate a std::string with more than 1 character I'm looking for?

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm writing a program that can take in multiple names separated by a space, like `"John Paul Andrew"` and turns the names into keys for a std::map.

It works fine with two names, but three names or more separate the string into:

```
Andrew
John
John Paul
```

Here's how I'm splitting the strings:

```
for (int i = 0; i < names.size() - 1; i++) {
        std::string::size_type pos = names.find(" ", i);

        std::cout << "Position of space: " << pos << std::endl; // For debugging

        if (pos != std::string::npos) {
            std::string name = names.substr(0, pos);
            scoreboard[name] = 0;
        } else {
            std::string name = names.substr(names.rfind(" ") + 1);
            scoreboard[name] = 0;
        }

}
```

Is there a replacement for `names.substr(0, pos);` I can use to fix the issue?

Comment: Consider `names.substr(0, pos);` carefully.

Comment: I did, but I didn't really know what to replace it with

Comment: You could have initialize `old_pos = 0;`, then use `names.substr(old_pos, pos - old_pos);`, and afterwards store `old_pos = pos + 1;`.

Comment: I'll try that. Thanks!

Comment: Alright, I just tried that and it still shows the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looping through *each character* of `names` (except the *last* character!), using the current loop position as the *starting* position to `find()` a space character.  That is not the logic you should be using.

Let's follow the logic, using your example of `"John Paul Andrew"` as the `names` to split.

- On the 1st-5th loop iterations, where `i` is `0..4`, `names.find(" ", i)` returns 4 each time. You then call `names.substr(0, 4)` which returns `"John"`.  So you assign 0 to `scoreboard["John"]` **5 times**.
- On the 6th-10th loop iterations, where `i` is `5..9`, `names.find(" ", i)` returns 9 each time. You then call `names.substr(0, 9)` which returns `"John Paul"`.  So you assign 0 to `scoreboard["John Paul"]` **5 times**.
- On the 11th-15th loop iterations, where `i` is `10..14`, `names.find(" ", i)` returns `std::string::npos` each time. You then call `names.rfind(" ")` which returns 9, and then you call `names.substr(9 + 1)` which returns `"Andrew"`.  So you assign 0 to `scoreboard["Andrew"]` **5 times**.

See the problem now?

At the very least, since you are looping through `names` one character at a time anyway, you should not be using `names.find()` at all, eg:

```cpp
std::string::size_type start = 0;

for (std::string::size_type i = 0; i < names.size(); ++i) { // <-- no -1 !
    if (names[i] == ' ') {
        std::cout << "Position of space: " << i << std::endl; // For debugging
        if (i > start) {
            std::string name = names.substr(start, i - start);
            scoreboard[name] = 0;
        }
        start = i + 1;
    }
}

if (start < names.size()) {
    std::string name = names.substr(start);
    scoreboard[name] = 0;
}
```

Which, if you really want to use `find()`, can be re-written more like this:

```cpp
std::string::size_type start = names.find_first_not_of(' ');
std::string name;

while (start != std::string::npos)
{
    std::string::size_type pos = names.find(' ', start);
    if (pos == std::string::npos)
    {
        name = names.substr(start);
        start = pos;
    }
    else
    {
        name = names.substr(start, pos - start);
        start = names.find_first_not_of(' ', pos + 1);
    }

    scoreboard[name] = 0;
}
```

However, there is a must easier way to split a string on spaces (and other whitespace characters):

```cpp
std::istringstream iss(names);
std::string name;

while (iss >> name)
{
    scoreboard[name] = 0;
}
```

Comment: Using ````std::istringstream```` is the better answer . . .  +1

Comment: The `std::istringstream` method works perfectly! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have `i` as you indexer, which can help you find the word being processed.  So you don't need an `old_pos` as I had suggested, since `i` already can serve that purpose.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

using std::cout;
using std::map;
using std::string;

static auto make_scoreboard(string names) -> map<string, int> {
    auto scoreboard = map<string, int>{};

    for (decltype(names.size()) i = 0; i < names.size() - 1; i++) {
        auto pos = names.find(" ", i);

        cout << "Position of space: " << pos << "\n"; // For debugging

        if (pos != string::npos) {
            auto name = names.substr(i, pos - i);
            scoreboard[name] = 0;
            i = pos;
        } else {
            string name = names.substr(names.rfind(" ") + 1);
            scoreboard[name] = 0;
            i = names.size();
        }
    }

    return scoreboard;
}


int main() {
    auto names = string{"John Paul Andrew"};
    auto scoreboard = make_scoreboard(names);

    for(auto&& s : scoreboard) {
        cout << s.first << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: ````auto scoreboard = map<string, int>{};```` ??? ````decltype(names.size())```` ??? Really? Too many autos . . .

Comment: @ArminMontigny • a former co-worker of mine suggested [almost always auto](https://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/).